# match value to a column name to create new variable in R

Tags: r

I have a dataset that looks like this

```
    students <- data.frame(name = c("student1", "student2", "student3", "student4"),
                   test1 = c(50, 30, 20, 6),
                   test2 = c(30, 20, 15, 10),
                   select = c("test2", "test1", "test2", "test1"))
```

Is there a way to create a new variable called 'grade' that will contain the test score of whatever variable appears in 'select'?

Sample output here:

```
    students <- data.frame(name = c("student1", "student2", "student3", "student4"),
                   test1 = c(50, 30, 20, 6),
                   test2 = c(30, 20, 15, 10),
                   select = c("test2", "test1", "test2", "test1"),
                   grade = c(30, 30, 15, 6))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple base-R solution...

```
students$grade <- sapply(1:nrow(students),
                         function(i) students[i, as.character(students$select[i])])

students
      name test1 test2 select grade
1 student1    50    30  test2    30
2 student2    30    20  test1    30
3 student3    20    15  test2    15
4 student4     6    10  test1     6
```

Or, to answer the follow up question in the comments - to cope with entries like `"test1, test2"`, you could do

```
students$grade <- sapply(1:nrow(students),
                  function(i) paste(students[i,                                   
                                   trimws(unlist(strsplit(students$select[i], ",")))],
                                    collapse=", "))
```

This basically takes each row and splits `select` at commas, trims whitespace, and then pastes the resulting `grade` values together.

So, if `students$select[1]` is `"test1, test2"` in the above, this produces

```
students
      name test1 test2       select  grade
1 student1    50    30 test1, test2 50, 30
2 student2    30    20        test1     30
3 student3    20    15        test2     15
4 student4     6    10        test1      6
```

Note that the `grade` column will now be forced to `character` format

Comment: thanks for this! easily used for n types of tests. Is there anywhere I could read up on the details of this code?

Comment: @imprela The `sapply` is just a loop - it goes through each item of its first argument (the row numbers of `students`) and applies the function in its second argument to each one. The function is just to lookup the element of `students` in row `i`, and in the column name specified by the value of the `select` column for row `i`.  The `as.character` changes the `select` element from a factor to a character string.  To see help on any function just type a question mark before it at the console (or RStudio) - e.g. `?sapply`.

Comment: Wow thanks for the detailed explanation. This was really helpful!

Comment: is there a way to do a string match instead of exact match? for example in the `select` column of student1 it shows "test2, test1", and I want in the grade column to appear as "50, 30" ?

Comment: @imprela Yes, although it is a bit more complicated - see one possibility added to the answer above.

Comment: This works just as what I wanted. Thank you so much @Andrew!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a Base R solution:

```
students$value = with(students, ifelse(select == 'test1', test1, test2))
```

or with `case_when` from `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)

students %>%
  mutate(value = case_when(
    select == 'test1' ~ test1, 
    TRUE ~ test2))
```

This solution also extends to `n` tests.

**Result:**

```
      name test1 test2 select value
1 student1    50    30  test2    30
2 student2    30    20  test1    30
3 student3    20    15  test2    15
4 student4     6    10  test1     6
```

Comment: Thanks! It works. any hint on how to extend it to n tests? I tried to add in 'test2' ~ test2, 'test3' ~ test3 and it gives me this error: Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots)

Comment: @imprela You will need `select == "testn" ~ testn` for every `test`, except for the last one where you specify `TRUE ~ testn`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this in base R, and you only have a small number of tests to select from, you can do this with the code:

```
students$Grade[students$select=="test1"] <- as.numeric(students$test1[students$select=="test1"])
students$Grade[students$select=="test2"] <- as.numeric(students$test2[students$select=="test2"])
```

Result:

```
      name test1 test2 select Grade
1 student1    50    30  test2    30
2 student2    30    20  test1    30
3 student3    20    15  test2    15
4 student4     6    10  test1     6
```